# Table view automatic dimension not fit when change table font size by code

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

when use table view xib cell I have label and I set contraint top, right, left, bottom to content view with lines zero and table view automatic dimension work fine in this case.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeue() as NotificationCell
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 1000
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
    
}
```

when change label font size programmatically in

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    label.font = UIFont(name: "fontName", size: 20)
}
```

the problem here cell height was on old font label size take from storyboard, heights only correct after scrolling and table view reload

Comment: Checked it, but seems to work correctly for me. Do you have any errors in the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because awakeFromNib() is called after the cell sizes have been determined. I will suggest you set the font size before awakeFromNib() is called. One suggestion will be:

```
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel! {
    didSet{
       label.font = UIFont(name: "fontName", size: 20)
    }
}
```

This way you are setting the font size before layout subviews is called by the superview.